# To what extent are the data stored with dokku postgres plugin persistent?

Tags: postgresql, dokku

To what extent are the data stored with [dokku postgres plugin](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-postgres) persistent, i.e. do they survive:

1. a re-deployment of the linked app
2. an upgrade of the postgres container
3. a reboot of the server

If they're persistent: where is the data stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data persists past all of those events. Data is stored in `/var/lib/dokku/services/postgres/SERVICE_NAME`.

Comment: It seems the folder have been moved to `/var/lib/dokku/services/postgres/SERVICE_NAME`.
At least is where mine is.